# Set this height if the other height is bigger (jquery and variables)

Tags: jquery, css, if-statement, height, var

I did some `if` sentences in order to equal the height of all the columns (`#col1`, `#col2` and `#col3`). However, for some reason I can get the value using `.css()` function, but can't make it work when I try to set that value I've got from other `var`.

This is my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    var col1_height = $('#col1').css('height');
    var col2_height = $('#col2').css('height');
    var col3_height = $('#col3').css('height');

    if (col1_height < col2_height){
        $('#col1').css('height', col2_height);
    }

    if (col1_height < col3_height){
        $('#col1').css('height', col3_height);  
    }

    if (col2_height < col1_height){
        $('#col2').css('height', col1_height);
    }

    if (col2_height < col3_height){
        $('#col2').css('height', col3_height);
    }

    if (col3_height < col1_height){
        $('#col3').css('height', col1_height);
    }

    if (col3_height < col2_height){
        $('#col3').css('height', col2_height);
    }
});
```

Here's my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Arkl1te/aNcYC/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
var newHeight = 0;
$('#col1, #col2, #col3').find('.content').each(function(){
    var temp = $(this).height();
    newHeight = temp > newHeight ? temp : newHeight;
}).css('height', newHeight);
```

This loops through each column's `.content` and compares each element's height with `newHeight`. If the current height is greater than `newHeight` then `newHeight` is set to this value.

Once the loop has finished all the `.content` elements are given the largest one's height.

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/aNcYC/2/

Comment: This is the way everybody does to make an if statement: `temp > newHeight ? temp : newHeight;`. I've never knew how it works. :/

Comment: @Fabián - it's really useful, you can read more about it here: [Conditional Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). It's best used when you're doing a simple check like the one in my answer. Using it for more complex comparisons can lead to your code  becoming hard to read and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I dont check it but `.css('height')` return string with `px` on end ... use `.height()` or `parseInt($(selector).css('height'))`.

Comment: It's true that I can use `.height()` to get and set a value.  
But what if I need to edit a more specific css property (as a matter of fact, values in css uses the value with `px`, so if the string has `'900px'`, it should set the same, but it doesn't :[ )